# Customize page numbering so all pages are equally formatted in book class

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

The title says it all. A friend is working on her thesis and we cannot figure out how to ensure that the page numbering is equally formatted on all the pages that display page numbers.

Default positioning has the page numbers altering left and right on even and odd pages, and at the bottom of the first page of every chapter.

Ideally she wants the the page numbers on every page printed on the top right corner of her book with no special formatting added for the first page of a chapter.

Any experience with this kind of customization?

---

Edit:

An MWE was requested and is therefore supplied.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
Special chapter title page. Page number positioned at bottom of page


\pagebreak
Normal body text. Page number positioned at top left corner of page.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps all you need to do is turn off two-sided mode? If you have "twoside" set as a document option (on the \documentclass line), just take it out. If it's not that simple please post a MWE.

Comment: Are you stuck with the `book` class?  If not try changing to `\documentclass{report}` and then put `\pagestyle{headings}` right after the `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get all pages formatted with a page number in the center of the footer is quite simple with [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

## MWE 1

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
Special chapter title page. Page number positioned at bottom of page.


\pagebreak
Normal body text. Page number positioned at bottom of page again.
\end{document}
```

If you want all pages to have the number in the upper right, it's a tiny bit more complicated but still quite doable, see Section 7 of [the fancyhdr manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).

## MWE 2

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\rhead{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
Special chapter title page. Page number positioned at top right.

\pagebreak
Normal body text. Page number positioned at top right again.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE is confusing; I think she wants all page numbers top right.

Comment: That can also be done with [fancyhdr](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf); see Section 7 of the manual.  I'll add a 2nd MWE.